# How do I group CoreData results by hour and sum their totals using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, group-by

I have step data stored in CoreData which has an entity that looks like this:

```
-Attribute-    -Type-
  steps        Double
  date         Date
```

I would like to retrieve the total number of steps for each hour in the day.
So far my query looks like this:

```
        let activityFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Steps")
        activityFetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

        let hourInDay = NSExpressionDescription()
        hourInDay.name = "hourInDay"
        hourInDay.expression = NSExpression(format: "FUNCTION(date,'hourInDay')")
        hourInDay.expressionResultType = .Integer16AttributeType

        let sumSteps = NSExpressionDescription()
        sumSteps.name = "sumOfSteps"
        sumSteps.expression = NSExpression(format: "sum:(steps)")
        sumSteps.expressionResultType = .DoubleAttributeType

        activityFetch.propertiesToFetch = [sumSteps, hourInDay]
        activityFetch.propertiesToGroudpBy = [hourInDay]

        var activityResults:NSArray = []
        do {
            //Success
            activityResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(activityFetch)
            for result in activityResults{
                print("  Result: \(result)")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            //Failure
            print ("   fetch Activities failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

I am using a helper function that returns the hour of each timestamp:

```
func hourInDay(date:NSDate) -> Int{
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: date)
}
```

When I run the function, I currently receive an NSInvalidArgumentExecption:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath expression ((<NSExpressionDescription: 0x129337160>), name hourInDay, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity (null), renamingIdentifier hourInDay, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}) passed to setPropertiesToFetch:'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What store type are you using?  (I think it will not work with a SQLite store).

Comment: Your `hourInDay` is not a valid `NSExpression`. Take a look at [the docs for `expressionForFunction:arguments:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:) to see what's valid.